# Deleted my SQL Server in object explorer in SQL Server Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

I accidentally deleted my SQL Server in the Object explorer in SQL Server Manager, since then I cannot connect to the server. Here is an image showing the error message:

http://s30.postimg.org/jki52mtf5/Untitled.png

The error is

> Login Failed for user G33K\Alaeddin (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456

Comment: from the error message, the reason for the error you are getting is solely connected to either wrong credentials (wrong user/password) or wrong database to which you are trying to connect.

Comment: That means that your windows account no longer has access to the SQL Server. Are you sure you always connected with Windows Authentication?

Comment: As Nick is implying, try SQL Server Authentication (change the dropdown from Windows Authentication), assuming that you have a username and password.

Comment: Yes I'm always connecting to the server using Windows Authentication, it just happened yesterday when I deleted the serve from the Object Explorer, I even tried to reinstall the SQL Server Management Studio but didn't work.

Comment: I think you need to speak with your SQL Administrator or Server Admin Team.  I suspect that either your credentials are invalid, you were previously connecting with a SQL account or a service has stopped on the server.  There isn't much you can do from your workstation I'm afraid.